# How to replace downloaded binary file with one downloaded from software manager?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, firefox

I have downloaded the firefox (quantum) .tar.bz2 , how to replace (not use side by side),the older version of firefox (which is there by default) with the downloaded firefox executable?

Comment: Doing so is not a good idea as you would be replacing system files outside of apt. This can result in conflicts with system libs, especially with a large package such as firefox, and / or , less likley, break apt. Use a ppa https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next (I believe this is quantum) . If not, just wait for the release and I am sure  there will be a ppa soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would extract the .tar version in `/opt/` and then edit the launcher to point to the binary inside `/opt/firefox/`. The launcher is probably in `/usr/share/applications/desktop.firefox`.

Make a local copy (that one takes precedence) en edit it from command line with:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Replace `firefox` in the `Exec` to `/opt/firefox/firefox` and the launcher icon will start the new version.

If you rename the launcher to `firefox2.desktop` you can have 2 launchers for firefox and start both ...

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/firefox2.desktop
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox2.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the beta, Firefox quantum is in the firefox-next ppa

https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade firefox
```

Installing from the ppa is better , IMO , than manually replacing system files. It is easily reversed and will not cause system conflicts.

[image: Quantum]